# How to download and install DB2 ODBC drivers for my laptop for remote connection to the server

Tags: database, odbc

Im failing to locate DB2 ODBC DRIVERS on IBM server for me to download and install for remote connection

I tried to download but the file I got doesn't have a setup to run as an administrator. What should i do to habe DB2 ODBC drivers on my windows 11 laptop?